# How do I merge two dictionaries in C#

Tags: c#, data-structures

Consider the following situation...

- A user belongs to one or more groups
- Group has one or many permissions
- Permission is defined as id and a vector of booleans (for read, write, etc). The vector is about a dozen predefined elements

I need to get an aggregate list of user permissions. In pseudocode, I get all permissions from first group that the user belongs to; and then for subsequent groups, I add new permissions, but for existing ones I need to OR all permissions in the vector. That is, if one group has permissions to read, and another has permissions to write - the user will have the permission to read **and** write.

The operation is not very frequent; so performance is not a big concern.

I am thinking of a Dictionary for the permission vector (C# equivalent of associative array. Theoretically, I can represent it in a normal array, but it feels too error-prone). Say,

```
var permVector = new Dictionary<string, bool> {
    {"read", true}, {"delete", false} ...
}
```

Then permissions for a group is another Dictionary

```
var groupPermissions = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, bool>> {
   { 1, permVector }...
}
```

(This comes from the database; I am showing this way here just for clarity)

And finally, user permissions would be an intelligent merge of all group permissions. And this is where I feel I am going down the rabbit hole.

Are there any types that are better suited for this task?

Comment: If you create your own data structures then you can control add, merging etc yourself. But either way, you're going to have to write the code that does it. LINQ is always a good option

Comment: Is there a specific question about dictionary merging here? Seems more general than that.

First suggestion would be to use an enum instead of strings for the permissions. Possibly with ascending values based on things that override each other, or as a [Flags] enum so you can OR them together as you mention. 

Second, agreed with @CallumLinington that you should strongly consider writing your own class to manage these, then you can tinker with the internal implementation (and ask questions about that :)

Comment: First permission can be done with a single integer (like unix) where you have system (read, write, execute), group (read, write, execute), user (read, write, execute) so permissions can be 9 bit of an integer.  Then you have a dictionary which should contain a list not a singular like Dictionary<string, List<string>> where the key is group names and the values are usernames, or the key is the username and the values are group names.

Comment: It's not very clear what you are struggling with. You have a `List<Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, bool>>>` with all user's group-permissions, is that correct? How you want to merge them? What is the expected result(we need sample data and a desired result)?

Comment: Thank you all, even the person who quietly downvoted the question. Probably use of word "permission" was confusing. Think of real-life permissions: "can I open the window", or "put a nail in the wall", etc. There is no overlap. The gist of the question was *did I choose right data structure*, given the problems I ran into - or there is a better choice. Fortunately, the question was clear enough for @Dennis_E - he not only confirmed that Dictionary *is* a reasonable choice, but also gave an advice how to merge. If that is not enough, custom class is a good advice for the future as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ query to merge all the permissions together:

```
var userPermissions =
    groupPermissions
        .SelectMany(pv => pv.Value) //Select all the Dictionaries
        .GroupBy(pv => pv.Key) //Get each permission into its own group
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, //Create the result
            g => g.Any(permission => permission.Value));
```

Comment: Thank you. No idea why my question was downvoted - but I guess, getting a short and clear answer from somebody who understood it just fine is well worth it!